# What is the regex for "Any positive integer, excluding 0"

Tags: java, regex

How can `^\d+$` be improved to disallow `0`?

EDIT (Make it more concrete):

**Examples to allow:**
1
30
111
**Examples to disallow:**
0
00
-22

It doesn't matter if positive numbers with a leading zero are allowed or not (e.g. `022`).

This is for Java JDK Regex implementation.

Comment: Do you want to accept, for example, `076`?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: But I can sacrifice this feature for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: “Any positive integer, excluding 0” note that 0 is not a positive integer.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

...and some padding to exceed 30 character SO answer limit :-).

[Here is Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BlHg0v/1)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do we need \d+ at the end? Why wouldn't `^[1-9]+$` work?

Comment: @mtahmed: `^[1-9]+$` would not allow 10

Comment: It will allow 1. "\d*" does also match the empty string.

Comment: @mtahmed `^[1-9]+$` would not allow `10`. @Mulmoth the suggestion will allow `1`, since `\d*` matches zero or more times. However, it will not allow `076`, as that doesn't start with a `[1-9]`.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: He changed `^[1-9]\d+$` to `^[1-9]\d*$` after my comment, which I deleted afterwards.

Comment: But what about `01`?

Comment: Why `^[1-9]\d?$` does not allow 100 and more? It's a question mark `?` sign after `\d`

Comment: To allow 0, change the expression into `^[0-9]\d*$` or `^\d*[1-9]\d*$` then it will accept 01 and 10.

Answer (score 82):

Sorry to come in late but the OP wants to allow `076` but probably does NOT want to allow `0000000000`.

So in this case we want a *string of one or more digits containing at least one non-zero*.  That is

```
^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Comment: This seems to fulfill what the OP wanted

Comment: i want positive integer and positive decimal. you have any solution?

Comment: You should ask that as a new question rather than as a comment. But spoiler: `^[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)$` but that is making an assumption about what you mean by "decimal." Do you need exponent parts? This is pretty involved, so ask another question.

Comment: +1 for considering corner case! BTW this pattern will work exactly the same: **`^0*[1-9]\d*$`** since the first `[0-9]*` is active only until `[1-9]` finds first non-zero i.e. it's active only until there are initial zeros (`0*` ).

Comment: Yes, that's the best one.

Comment: This is the right answer. It accepts 00098 which is the correct behavior as per question.

Answer (score 22):

You might try a negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!0+$)\d+$
```

Comment: This allows 01, 02, etc…

Comment: @Matijs the question was written such that this is okay and expected. To disallow any leading zeros, it should suffice to simplify the lookahead to `(?!0)`.

Answer (score 19):

Try this one, this one works best to suffice the requiremnt.

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

Here is the sample output

```
String 0 matches regex: false
String 1 matches regex: true
String 2 matches regex: true
String 3 matches regex: true
String 4 matches regex: true
String 5 matches regex: true
String 6 matches regex: true
String 7 matches regex: true
String 8 matches regex: true
String 9 matches regex: true
String 10 matches regex: true
String 11 matches regex: true
String 12 matches regex: true
String 13 matches regex: true
String 14 matches regex: true
String 15 matches regex: true
String 16 matches regex: true
String 999 matches regex: true
String 2654 matches regex: true
String 25633 matches regex: true
String 254444 matches regex: true
String 0.1 matches regex: false
String 0.2 matches regex: false
String 0.3 matches regex: false
String -1 matches regex: false
String -2 matches regex: false
String -5 matches regex: false
String -6 matches regex: false
String -6.8 matches regex: false
String -9 matches regex: false
String -54 matches regex: false
String -29 matches regex: false
String 1000 matches regex: true
String 100000 matches regex: true
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't add any value or elegance when compared to the accepted answer `[1-9]\d*`.

Comment: @Zeemee that is not correct as \d might include numerals that are not 0-9. For example Arabic numerals like واحد in some libraries.

Comment: @dummyDev I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for mentioning!

Comment: Sadly this will return true for "123abcd".

Comment: Charith Jayasanka - yes, it still needs a ^ at the beginning and a "$" at the end :-)

Answer (score 11):

`^\d*[1-9]\d*$`

this can include all positive values, even if it is padded by Zero in the front

Allows

1

01

10

11  etc

do not allow

0

00

000 etc..

Comment: For some reason this was not working in the pattern attribute of JSP page, the other pattern that helped , [0]*[1-9][0-9]*
Ref URL: https://www.toolbox.com/tech/programming/question/regular-expression-nonzero-values-083109/

Answer (score 4):

Any positive integer, excluding 0: `^\+?[1-9]\d*$`   
Any positive integer, including 0: `^(0|\+?[1-9]\d*)$`

Answer (score 3):

You might want this (edit: allow number of the form `0123`):

```
^\\+?[1-9]$|^\\+?\d+$
```

however, if it were me, I would instead do

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(s)
if (x > 0) {...}
```

Comment: Two problems: This also matches "123abc", and returns 123, and this might throw a ParseException.

Comment: @Daniel: I guess this might be used inside a larger parsing scheme, therefore you would have a regex/BNF that captures digits only, and a java code to check that the captured digits are non-zero positive.

Comment: @Daniel: in any case, you would still need the data as an integer and so sooner or later you would still need to call parseInt() or roll your own parseInt().

Comment: @Daniel: `Integer.parseInt()` itself adds very little overhead. It's the throwing and catching of exceptions that's expensive.

Comment: @Lie: what's the deal with the `\\+?` prefixes?  I'm guessing that's supposed to be an escaped plus sign as it would appear in Java source code, but why?  If minus signs aren't allowed, I think it's safe to assume plus signs are out, too.

Comment: @Alan Moore: +10 == 10 so if the OP want to have a lax matching, then he might want to allow an optional plus sign.

Comment: I think lax *specifying* is our real problem. ;)  But @Daniel  is right about the error in your regex.  If you don't enclose the alternation in its own group, like so: `^\+?(?:[1-9]|\d+)$`, it will match any string that *starts* with `[1-9]` (like `1foo`) or *ends* with `[0-9]` (like `bar2`).  @Mulmoth's [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0/7036362#7036362) has the same problem.

Comment: @Alan Moore,@Daniel: ah, I see what you meant, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Got this one:

```
^[1-9]|[0-9]{2,}$
```

Someone beats it? :)

Comment: This would allow `00` Do you want this? And it will allow `1aaaaa` and `abcd01`. `^` belongs only to the first alternative and `$` only to the second, to solve this put brackets around it `^([1-9]|[0-9]{2,})$`

Comment: Well, this accepts `000000000`.  You did say any integer _excluding zero_.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, another alternative using lookaheads:

```
^(?=\d*[1-9])\d+$
```

As many digits as you want, but at least one must be `[1-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx matches any Integer positive out of 0:

```
(?<!-)(?<!\d)[1-9][0-9]*
```

It works with two negative lookbehinds, which search for a minus before a number, which indicates it is a negative number. It also works for any negative number larger than -9 (e.g. -22).

Answer (score 0):

My pattern is complicated, but it covers exactly "Any positive integer, excluding 0" (1 - 2147483647, not long). 
It's for decimal numbers and doesn't allow leading zeros.

```
^((1?[1-9][0-9]{0,8})|20[0-9]{8}|(21[0-3][0-9]{7})|(214[0-6][0-9]{6})
|(2147[0-3][0-9]{5})|(21474[0-7][0-9]{4})|(214748[0-2][0-9]{3})
|(2147483[0-5][0-9]{2})|(21474836[0-3][0-9])|(214748364[0-7]))$
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, but match the exact range 1..2147483647

```
^(214748364[0-7]|21474836[0-3]\d|2147483[0-5]\d{2}|214748[0-2]\d{3}|21474[0-7]\d{4}|2147[0-3]\d{5}|214[0-6]\d{6}|21[0-3]\d{7}|20\d{8}|1\d{9}|[1-9]\d{0,8})$
```

Note:

- 2000000000 to 2147483647 -> `214748364[0-7]|21474836[0-3]\d|2147483[0-5]\d{2}|214748[0-2]\d{3}|21474[0-7]\d{4}|2147[0-3]\d{5}|214[0-6]\d{6}|21[0-3]\d{7}|20\d{8}`
- 1000000000 to 1999999999 -> `1\d{9}`
- 1 to 999999999 -> `[1-9]\d{0,8}`

Answer (score -2):

^[1-9]*$ is the simplest I can think of

Comment: This regular expression will erroneously fail to match numbers such as `10` and `29303`.  It will also match empty string.

Answer (score -3):

This should only allow decimals > 0

```
^([0-9]\.\d+)|([1-9]\d*\.?\d*)$
```