# PHP - cannot find correct regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to figure out a regex that would match `012` but wound't match `0`.
So basically if the string is one character and that character equals `0` then it should false but it should work with values like `012`, `023`, `01`, `05`, `120`.

I tried that but it doesn't do what i want.

```
^(?=[^0])(?=[0-9]{1,3})$
```

Any idea?

Comment: ^(?=\d*[1-9])\d+$

Gleamed from: [stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?!0$)\d+$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/27

Comment: Awesome, can you please explain?

Comment: ^(?!0$)[0-9]{1,3}$ , look ahead expression, except when it is starting and ending with 0, it will match others

Comment: @pit_ns for explaination you probably can take a look at right side of the link that provided

Comment: @pit_ns it captures all numbers but uses negative lookahead to see if a number is just 0.