# REGEX for whole, positive number

Tags: regex

I am trying to create an input regex that will only accept whole, positive numbers. So far I have:

[^[+]?\d+([.]\d+)?$]

But users can still enter, say, .4. How can I alter this to disallow floats? Thanks!

Comment: but your current regex `\d+([.]\d+)?` allows floats , actually

Comment: Are you wanting to disallow floats altogether, or accept whole positive numbers eg 123.00 ?

Comment: yes, I would like to disallow floats altogether. So 123 would be accepted but 123.00 would not. The input field is for a number of people, so it would be odd for someone to enter in 123.00

Answer (score 1):

This allows only positive numbers

```
^[0-9]+$
```

Comment: This helped me! Would have even more been helpful if it explained why.

Answer (score 1):

I think you try to filter only positive integers.

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

allows only positive integer numbers. [What is the regex for "Any positive integer, excluding 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0)  will also help you.

Answer (score -1):

Use only `^[+]?\d+$`

you can see the test cases [here](https://regex101.com/r/hWN8Op/1)