# Complex regular expression routing filter wildcard Laravel 5.4

Tags: regex, routes, laravel-5.4

I try to filter my route like following :

```
Route::post('/vote/{bandId}', 'VoteController@vote')->where('bandId', '[0-9]+');
```

But it allows the following route :

```
http://localhost/vote/0
```

Which I do not want since I am fetching the resource from a query by filtering on the auto-increment field (which is greater than 0).

I tryied to type an advanced regex like I would do with `preg_match()` :

```
Route::post('/voter/{bandId}', 'VoteController@vote')->where('bandId', '[1-9][0-9]*');
```

Which let numbers between 1 and infinite.

**Question**

This last route does not works, how can I come with a complex regular expression to check the integrity of my wildcard before fetching the resource in my database ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex:

`^[1-9]\d*$`

Source:
[What is the regex for "Any positive integer, excluding 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0)