# MVC 5 Data Annotation "Not Equal to Zero"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

Probably I am missing something, but having the model below

```
 public class MyModel
 {
     public double WhateverButNotZero { get; set; }
 }
```

is there any MVC built-in DataAnnotation to validate the number as "everything but zero"?

Comment: [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx) is the list of all DataAnnotation attributes available. Fast answer: no, there's none

Comment: There is no built in `ValidationAttribute`, but you can use a [foolproof](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=foolproof) `[NotEqualTo]` attribute, or if you want to learn to write your own conditional validation attributes, refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in validation for that specifically, but you can create a custom attribute for it if you don't want to use regex as mentioned in other answers.

1. Create a class that extends the `ValidationAttribute` class
2. Override the `IsValid(object value)` method
3. Inside your validation method, convert the object to `int` and check if it's equal zero

```
public class NotZeroAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value) => (int)value != 0;
}
```

Then just use it on your class property like that:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [NotZero]
    public double WhateverButNotZero { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is not built-in, but surely the one I like the most. Functional, simple and clean.

Comment: Won't this return `false` for e.g. `0.1` because of the truncation?

Answer (score 5):

[Regex to the rescue:](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

```
public class MyModel
{
    [RegularExpression("(.*[1-9].*)|(.*[.].*[1-9].*)")]
    public double WhateverButNotZero { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @SBFrancis, your answer works good, but it accepts letters in some cases
Example: https://regex101.com/r/v4xi46/2/

Comment: But that shouldn't be possible with a double datatype.

Answer (score 2):

Way I do it, and I think the easiest way

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Value must be greater than zero.")]
```

Comment: what about negative values?

Comment: My solution obviously doesn't handle negative numbers. This works only for positive numbers

Comment: Indeed. But the question would like to achieve "any number but zero", which implies any possible number,  from negative to positive, with or without decimal point.  Your answer is good, but doesn't cover the actual question.

Answer (score 1):

try using `regex annotation`

```
public class MyModel
{
    [RegularExpression("^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)(\d+|\d*\.\d+)$", ErrorMessage = "Not Equal to Zero")]
    public double WhateverButNotZero { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegularExpression DataAnnotation attribute.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d*[1-9]\d*$")]
public double WhateverButNotZero { get; set; }
```

Hopefully, [What is the regex for “Any positive integer, excluding 0”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036324/what-is-the-regex-for-any-positive-integer-excluding-0) will be helpful to find out the regular expression as per your need.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what I'm looking for is "any number but zero". This means micro negatives or positives should be accepted, such as -0.0001, -0.0000000000001, 0.0123, etc

Comment: In that case, I think "^[+-]?([0-9]\.\d+)|([1-9]\d*\.?\d*)$", this regular expression will be helpful, it will allow micro negatives or positives integers.